# exec,Cmd.Run() does not properly run command w/arguments

Tags: windows, go, cmd

go version go1.15.6 windows/amd64
dev os Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]

I have a Go app in which I am running the AWS CLI using exec.Cmd.Run().  I build out the Cmd class and populate the arguments.

Before I run the Cmd, I use the .String() method to view the command to be ran.  If I take this value, copy it to a shell, the command executes with no modifications to the output given to me with no issues reported.

However, when I run the command, it fails returning an error.  When I debug the script, it is failing because it says the AWS CLI is saying a parameter is incorrect.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to see the 100% raw representation of what is being ran?  It does not match the return value of .String()
2. Is there a better way to call an os level command that I am missing?

Real Example:

```
cmd := &exec.Cmd{
    Path:   awsPath,
    Args:   args,
    Stdout: &stdout,
    Stderr: &stderr,
}

fmt.Printf("Command: %s\n", cmd.String())
// c:\PROGRA~1\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws.exe --profile testprofile --region us-east-1 --output json ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=group-id,Values=sg-abc123
// Running above works 100% of the time if ran from a shell window

err := cmd.Run()
// always errors out saying the format is incorrect
```

GoPlayground Replication of Issue
https://play.golang.org/p/mvV9VG8F0oz

Comment: Refer to https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd

Comment: We cannot what is incorrect about the format of your `args` and `awsPath` when you don’t show what they are.

Comment: Could you please show a little bit more code so I can re-produce and get into your situation? And what is the error output in your console?

Comment: @JimB, I am guessing you mean "We cannot tell what is incorrect"?  That was my bad, I thought that providing the output was clear in regards to what the values are.  I have edited my answer to include a go playground which demonstrates the issues.   Please note, however, that it can't be fully run online.

Answer (score 1):

From [cmd.String](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.15.6/src/os/exec/exec.go#L198) source:

```
// String returns a human-readable description of c.
// It is intended only for debugging.
// In particular, it is not suitable for use as input to a shell.
// The output of String may vary across Go releases.
```

You are seeing the reverse, but the problem is the same: eye-balling a printed command string does not show the exact executable path (is there a rogue space or unprintable character?), same with the arguments (rogue characters?).

Use `fmt.Printf("cmd : %q\n", cmd.Path)` to show any hidden unicode characters etc. And use the same technique with each of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
I have found the root cause of your problem you met: [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

> ```
> // Path is the path of the command to run.
> //
> // This is the only field that must be set to a non-zero
> // value. If Path is relative, it is evaluated relative
> // to Dir.
> Path string
>
> // Args holds command line arguments, including the command as **Args[0]**.
> // If the Args field is empty or nil, Run uses {Path}.
> //
> // In typical use, both Path and Args are set by calling Command.
> Args []string
> ```

So if you have declare the `Cmd.Path := "/usr/local/bin/aws"`, you have to declare `Cmd. Args` like this: `Args:   []string{"", "s3", "help"},` because the `Args` including the command as `Args[0]` in above document link.
Final, I think you can exec command like this for simple and effectively:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    stdout := &bytes.Buffer{}
    stderr := &bytes.Buffer{}

    name := "/usr/local/bin/aws"
    arg := []string{"s3", "help"}

    cmd := exec.Command(name, arg...)
    cmd.Stderr = stderr
    cmd.Stdout = stdout

    fmt.Printf("Command: %q\n", cmd.String())

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", stderr.String())
    }

    fmt.Println("Output: ", stdout.String())
}
=========
$ go run main.go
Command: "/usr/local/bin/aws s3 help"
```

Done.

Comment: might I suggest using `%q` e.g. `fmt.Printf("Command: %q\n", cmd.String())`. This will quote the string - but also show any unprintable and or bad unicode characters that would trip up an API but go undetected if `%s` is used.

Comment: Tks @colm.anseo, I have edited my answer and use your suggestion to improve, Tks

Comment: @colm.anseo I appreciate that very much!   I've noted this and will do this in the future!

Comment: @ThoQuach I'll give this a go in the A.M. and see where it lands.   I appreciate your help.